# Carrierwave: sometimes created version can not be found

Tags: ruby, carrierwave, minimagick

My Carrierwave uploader file is like this, and I've checked that the new version is created correctly. The problem is , sometimes the view part can't find the created version.

```
 class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :fog

  def store_dir
   "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def store_dimensions
     if file && model
      width, height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(file.file)[:dimensions]
        if width>700
              finalHeight=((700*height)/width)
              self.class.version :best_fit do
                process :resize_to_fill => [700,finalHeight]
              end
        else
              self.class.version :best_fit do
                process :resize_to_fill => [width,height]
              end
        end
        end
  end

#run the store_dimensions methods
  process :store_dimensions

end
```

The view file is like:

```
<%= image_tag pp.image_url(:best_fit), id: "plot-image-#{pp.id}" %>
```

After uploading, sometimes the page is displayed, sometimes the following message is shown:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Version best_fit doesn't exist!):
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to mention the following lines after the method. Apparently store_dimensions only works when the image is being uploaded. So, after that session expires, the version code won't be found. So the following two lines of code is necessary.

```
version :best do
end
```

So, the code would be like the following.
     process :store_dimensions

```
 def store_dimensions
     if file && model
      width, height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(file.file)[:dimensions]
        if width>700
              finalHeight=((700*height)/width)
              self.class.version :best do
                process :resize_to_fill => [700,finalHeight]
              end
        else
              self.class.version :best do
                process :resize_to_fill => [width,height]
              end
        end
      end
end


 #this would load compressed version during loading
 #if it is ommited, after restarting server, images won't be loaded
 version :best do
 end
```